# How can I relay mail to multiple SMTP servers?

Tags: exchange, smtp, gmail

We want to use Google Apps for Domains as our email service but the "corporate" office want's the emails in Exchange.  I would like to set up a relay (is that the proper term) to send any incoming mail to both, Google and Exchange.  That way, we can use Gmail for our daily communication (both sending & receiving) and the "corporate" people are happy getting a copy of our incoming stuff.

Or is this completely insane?  :)

Thanx!

Comment: You should really engage the corporate folks to work with you on this. By the sound of it, you're not a mail admin?

Comment: Agreed with @mfinni. We don't like it, but "Corporate" typically get to decide these sort of things. Setting things up as you propose is going to very quickly turn into a nightmare. While it is certainly possible to use two separate mail systems, it's not pretty, and typically becomes a rat's nest to manage.

Comment: Plus, there could easily be legal requirements about retention (and policy requirements about destruction) that you could end up subverting. Don't expose your company to lawsuits without getting all the facts from HR, Legal, and IT, because it will be your butt in the sling for doing this.

Comment: Another problem with this approach is that your users' Exchange mailboxes will fill with incoming messages and never be emptied. Also, outgoing messages will not be processed or archived by the corporate systems, if that's a requirement for your corporation.

Comment: If the corp office wants them in Exchange, why isn't your office using Exchange mailboxes delivered from corporate?  Why the need to be separate from what the rest of the company is doing?  You sure your IT security dept. is cool with this idea?  I would be shocked if they were, since outbound email still isn't routed through Exchange.

Comment: This is all very good feedback and we probably won't go through with the dual delivery plan.  Thanks for the help and advice!  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be (much) easier to do this if you had different SMTP domains but yes, you can create do this. See [Receiving routing - Use dual delivery](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2685650) under *Routing examples and use cases*.

Comment: Not split delivery - dual delivery. Richard Hurt wants all email copied to Exchange.

Comment: And "send routing".